# Why does my shared post call from graph api return empty result?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I am a researcher in the field of social media marketing and i am interested to find the shares information of a page's posts.

I used my own access token and was expecting that i could harvest a list of shares (Since i can see it on facebook.com)

However, such queries kept returning me an empty data array.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/127512302882_10152539472047883/sharedposts?access_token=[Insert a Token]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

1. The API is expecting the **POST_ID**. The ID that you are using is actually `PAGE-ID_POST-ID`, use only `POSTID` (10152539472047883) and it should work.
2. Also make sure that the access token you are using has the `read_stream` permission with it

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/sharedposts)

Comment: I did try the Post-id as well. it still returns me empty. and i used the app token ID . could that be the problem ?

Comment: What is *"app token ID"*? You should use a valid user access token

Comment: singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher